# Is Flash hardware acceleration assignable to a given GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, flash, gpu, linux-kvm

On a KVM Windows guest with VGA passthrough, Flash hardware acceleration is not working, e.g. it shows a green screen for youtube videos.
The GPU (AMD) is working well and has the latest drivers, Windows recognizes it and utilizes it without issues.

The technique I use for GPU passthrough is often referred to as secondary GPU, which means that the virtual machine boots on an emulated GPU and then switches to the real one.

My assumption is that the issue is not really related to virtual environment, but more simply to Flash choosing the primary (emulated) GPU rather than the secondary (real) GPU.
I searched for the possibility to let Flash know that it should use the second GPU, but couldn't find relevant results.

That's not a big issue and software rendering is working well enough for me, but maybe someone knows how Flash chooses the GPU in case there are multiple cards?